# Is there a way for force a check box in an SSRS report to always be check?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multi-select

I have a report with a multi select parameter. I would like make one of the options checked off, and always be checked. Even if the user clicks the box to unchecked it, it does not change, it continues to remain checked. BUT, I would like for other options in the drop down to be checked or unchecked as the users want.

Is there any way to do this, or is this impossible?

Comment: What is the point of this? If the user cannot change whether the value is selected, why include it in the multi-value parameter options at all?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to disable the checkbox generated for a multivalue parameter.

However I answer with a possible solution here.

Create another parameter as `internal` and populate it with the user selected values and the must value.

Supposing I have a visible parameter for selecting year. I want the 2013 value always be checked.

I created another parameter called `ActualYears` and set it as `internal` then in `default values` put this expression:

```
=split(join(Parameters!Year.Value,",") & ",2013",",")
```

Note the 2013 is added manually, if you want to add more than one value just add the values separated by commas.

Now you can use `ActualYears` parameter against your query or wherever you need to use it.

[image]

> The screenshot shows the user selection is only 2015. At right side I
>   put the `ActualYears` value in a textbox and casted it to string,
>   these are the values it contains note the 2013 mandatory year.

Let me know if this can help you.